# An Objective-C message was sent to a deallocated 'ViewController' object (zombie) at address: 0x10c272f80.

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I'm getting this error whenever I try to execute this line of code.

```
[myObject addTarget:banner action:@selector(goToTargetLink:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

This line of code runs once a background operation has finished. I have tried making the method that contains it both a class and instance method, but they both fail with the same error. The class that contains this line of code inherits from NSObject. There is another class (ViewController) that calls this code with

```
[myClass myFunction:self.view];
```

Any help is appreciated.. Thanks

Comment: You turned on Zombies in order to detect a dangling pointer and you have detected it. If you don't want to see the error, turn off Zombies (but of course then you may expect to crash instead).

Comment: Can you please post some more code, You probably deallocated the object before using that.

Comment: The ViewController `self` that is part of `self.view` has been deallocated because nothing else has a string reference to it.   Where is the `self` instance of ViewController created, and what, if anything, keeps a strong reference to it?